# Re-enabling the expired provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I Wanted to know if there is a way to re-enable the expired distribution provisioning profile without creating a new one.

Comment: If you are Agent , you can Edit the profile and generate it again

Comment: unfortunately the profile has been deleted and I can not edit it from developer's panel but I have the profile downloaded file. Is there anyway that I can upload the downloaded file to the panel? @chawki

Comment: no you can not !