# Uninstalling an iOS application using its bundle ID

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

Recently our provisioning profile expired, and we couldn't recover it for some [other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830170/re-enabling-the-expired-provisioning-profile) (Accidentally removed the profile from the developer panel). The only option for us to distribute our application again was to re-sign the app with a newly generated profile and ask our users to install the new one.
Now we face a UX problem which involves asking our users to uninstall the old version to be able to install the newly signed app. We can solve this problem by changing our bundle id. But this way, the user will face two applications with the same name and icon.
Is there any way to automatically uninstall our old application? Also, we will be grateful to get any other suggestion to help our users easy migration.

Edit: My question is to delete applications using the application that I'm developing not deleting the bundle id from the Apple developer panel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove bundle id in iOS development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077311/how-to-completely-remove-bundle-id-in-ios-development)

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to delete an iOS application that was using a specific bundle id using another iOS app (not deleting the APP ID in the developer panel).
the link above explains how to delete the App ID.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no way to uninstall an app from another app. The sandbox concept simply do not allow this. Only the App Store has the right to do that task and even Apple do not use it often.

From Apple point of view the user has to be in charge. Only the user should be able to uninstall an app. There is no need for an automatic uninstall if user is able to do it. So simply tell the user to uninstall it.

Just think about it. If it's possible to do that, you can invent an app that is able to remove any other apps (and the saved data of that apps!). As a user I hope that something like that isn't possible ;)

If you use Enterprise Management (MDM / EMM) to enroll your app you may be able to trigger an uninstall of your own apps installed by MDM/EMM by server side configuration. In that case you use the App Store functionality internally. It's the only exception from that rule. In that case the owner of the device is technically the company not the person that use the device. So the rule "user is in charge" is fulfilled too.

Comment: Actually, we do use an enterprise account and the app we want to delete is one of our own apps. but I don't know how to use the MDM/EMM solution. is there any tutorial or documentation?